# How to remove all TIMERS at a time in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In Test plan we have many uniform random Timers for each and very request. so now we need to remove all at time.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to run a test where they are ignored, set in user.properties:

> timer.factor=0.0f

See :

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#timer

Otherwise, remove them all and then use popup menu of Thread Group/Controller node :

> Add Think Times to children nodes